# macOS 13 is not selectable from macOS Deployment Target dropdown in Xcode 14

Tags: xcode, macos, deployment-target

**Context**

I am using `Xcode 14` and utilize some `SwiftUI` features that were added in `macOS 13`, like `String(localized:, defaultValue:)` and `NavigationStack` / `NavigationSplitView`. However, I do get `Compiler Errors` when doing so, it seems, that the `Compiler` does not recognize those new things.

> Extra argument 'defaultValue' in call

I checked the `Deployment Target` in `Project > Info` and `Project > Build Settings`, in the latter, the `Deployment Target` is set to `macOS 13`, however, in the former, it is not possible to select `macOS 13` from the dropdown menu.

---

**Image**

[image: Info and Build Settings]

---

**Question**

How can I update the `macOS Deployment Target` to `macOS 13`, so that I can use the new features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 14.0 does not contain the macOS 13 SDK because macOS 13 has not shipped yet. Because of this you can't use the latest features in macOS 13 or set the deployment target to macOS 13.

Use the Xcode 14.1 beta to use the new features in macOS 13.